# Make the box width(DYNAMIC) fit to its content

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Please see this code and image. If I resize the window, the red box stretches, but I want the red box's width always just fit for its content. (I do not want empty space at the right side) How to correct this?

[Kindly See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ8Za.jpg)

Please note : **Width** of the container, **widt**h of the items are all **dynamic**, and I cannot hard code a value like 100px;

( **inline-block not working**)

```css
   .main {
      border: 10px solid red;
      padding:10px;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      background-color:yellow!important;
    }
    
     .main div {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
       border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
  
    
    <div class="main" >
      <div style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
      <div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
      <div style="background-color:khaki;">C</div>
      <div style="background-color:pink;">D</div>
      <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
      <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How many items should fit in the container?

Comment: im pretty sure this wil be duplicate : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Don't re-ask the same question. [edit] your original question to explain WHY it is not a duplicate if that is what you think....but it is.

Comment: Pauline, I have gone through, and many similar in other forms, I believe my issue is unique. I get very close solutions but not exact. Kindly don't jump into mark as Duplicate. Persons like me are very much rely on this and other forums for learning. I hope you understand.

Comment: @phyle could you show **What** you've done from the duplicate, and what you mean by **not exact**? Cause this is as vague as vague can be. If you say "from duplicate X, I took Y, but Z happens instead of X".... it makes for an easier issue to solve.

Comment: @Patrice , How can I share my code here?

Comment: @Phyle Depends what you mean. Usually on stack it's highly suggested to make a "minimal" repro.... if you really have it, you should be able to include it entirely on this question, by editing it. No?

Comment: Tell me if there is anywhere in this stalkoverflow have solved this exact problem?

Comment: @Patricee No not allowed, maximum character limit.  You guys more worried about  somewhat matching question, rather than checking if its solved or not, or any uniqueness in it.

Comment: @phyle if you add an e to my name it won't ping me. And... I did mention 'minimal'. Are you sure this is what's minimally needed to reproduce your issue? The intent of asking for a minimal example is to : a)help **you** isolate your issue (in my case, isolating my issue usually shows me what's broken). And b)make sure your post is as minimal as needed. Look, I'm not trying to be difficult. I'm trying to *help you'*. Don't act as if I voted to close your question or I'm responsible for the size limit blocking you here. Be better and don't bite the hand that feeds, plz?

Comment: @Patrice thanks. I hope you have seen the image I attached to my question. I hope you have read my comments to "Rmaxx" about empty space after the boxes.  There are some nice tutorials on css-tricks website about how flex works. However there is no solution so far for my issue. Anywhere.   ( Please see, when you resize the window I do not want the last 2 boxes stretch to full width. Imagine if the grey box have a content "How are you?" and green box have "I am fine thank you very much!", Now, those boxes max width must be the length of the content. AND no empty space(width) on right.

Answer (score -2):

Like this?

```css
.main {
  border: 10px solid red;
  padding:10px;
  display: flex;
  
  flex-flow: wrap;
  background-color:yellow!important;
}

 .main div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.main div.nogrow{
  flex-grow: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main" >
  <div style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
  <div class="nogrow" style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
  <div style="background-color:khaki;">C</div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;">D</div>
  <div class="nogrow" style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
  <div class="nogrow" style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost!! and many thanks for your help. But, please see when you resize the window,  I do not want the last 2 boxes stretch to full. width. Imagine if the grey box have a contnet "How are you?" and green box has "I am fine thank you very much!", Now, those boxes max width must be the length of the content.

Comment: could you help on this please ?

Comment: well its downvoted twice, and it's closed.. but i updated the example for you.. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks !! But, if we add nogrow class to all child div, then it is not working.

Comment: Try adding "nogrow" and add some some text to divs (not single character like A), I tested and I can see the container width is stretching when resize. Wish I had a way to show you what I mean. :(

Comment: Here is a preview, try resizing the window.. https://jsfiddle.net/phyle5/07pwdy12/2/

Comment: nogrow should only apply to the boxes you want to put text in, so the ones that do not scale... you will HAVE to, in any solution make a distinction between the boxes you want to scale, and the ones you dont, OR make the maximum amount of boxes in a row (colums) fixed.

Comment: unfortunately, the content coming to the boxes are dynamic (json) . So I cannot set a width. Width of the boxes are not FIXED, and should NOT STRETCH to the entire width of container.

Comment: Not a fixed width, but a fixed number of cells per row. With the nogrow class they will not stretch. If you can NOT differ between the ones you want to scale and the ones you dont, for whatever reason, you simply can not do this.

Answer (score -2):

Use `display:inline-flex;` and `flex-grow: 1;` to the elements if you want to avoid empty spaces always.

```html
   <style>    
.main {
  border: 10px solid red;
  padding:10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color:yellow!important;
}

 .main div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
   
}
</style>

<body>


<div class="main" >
  <div style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
  <div style="background-color:khaki;">C</div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;">D</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your's is the most close solution I am looking for. Except the fact that the last 2 columns stretching to full width. Need content width only.  -- Imagine if the grey box have a content "How are you?" and green box have "I am fine thank you very much!", Now, those boxes max width must be the length of the content.

Comment: I am still struggling for a solution. Need to avoind the empty area(right side) of container. Content should not stretch. Any help?